# Web standards : schema or data-vocabulary

Tags: schema, web-standards

I am getting ready to update mock ups/tags of an e-commerce store. I am a bit confused which standards to implement on product elements, breadcrumbs and rest of the site. Does anyone know which standards should i follow and why?

Answer (score 0):

There are many vocabularies for products, for example:

- *GoodRelations* vocabulary:
  http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/Quickstart
- *schema.org Product* vocabulary:
  http://schema.org/Product

You should be able to use both vocabularies in **microdata** and/or **RDFa**: see http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/Microdata and http://schema.org/docs/datamodel.html

Comment: you are right, seems there are much more than expected: microdata, microformat, schema, rdf, goodrelations. Should try to implement all of them? is there any point to do this? also do each vocabulary requires different headers?

Comment: Note that GoodRelations is [now integrated](http://blog.schema.org/2012/11/good-relations-and-schemaorg.html) into schema.org.

Comment: It's possible to use several vocabularies, yes. It depends on your case if it's useful/possible. What is your main aim? E.g. if it is "only" SEO, you could stick to those vocabularies that the big search enginges parse (→ probably schema.org). If you are more into the Semantic Web, I guess you could also use ontologies to map your data to equivalent vocabularies (`owl:sameAs`)

Comment: your are right, since the reason for this is SEO we focus & implemented schema.org tags. Thank you for your help.